# AudioTrack and Google cast / Chrome cast

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, android-audiomanager, audiotrack

I am trying to enable `Google Cast` / `Chromecast` support to my audio app which decodes audio and writes the bytes to `AudioTrack` and play it.

I know that using audio files, it is very simple as I can just provide the url for the file and it works; but what about situations like mine? I could not find an example for this. Where can I find more information or do you have any experience with this kind of thing? (Adding `Google Cast` support to your live audio streaming app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cast media player needs a media source served over HTTP. You will need to provide a web server to access your audio data.